# how to append export counter csv output

Tags: powershell

Please advice how we can append the below script output.

```
$CtrList = @(
        "\System\Processor Queue Length",
        "\Memory\Pages/sec",
        "\Memory\Available MBytes",
        "\Processor(*)\% Processor Time",
        "\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Received/sec",
        "\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Sent/sec",
        "\LogicalDisk(C:)\% Free Space",
        "\LogicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk Queue Length"
        )
    Get-Counter -Counter $CtrList -SampleInterval 5 -MaxSamples 5 | Export-Counter -Path C:\Example.csv -FileFormat CSV -Force
```

Comment: "append the below script output" to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the cleanest approach would involve outputting your counter directly to a CSV string, but since there is no such function, we'll have to use a temp file to stage the data.

```powershell
# NOTE: I removed your -Counters parameter, just add them back.

# output file, temp file, and number of samples
$outputFile = "c:\temp\output.csv" ;
$tempFile = "$($outputFile).tmp" ;
$maxSamples = 5;

# export the CSV to tmp file
Get-Counter -SampleInterval 5 -MaxSamples $maxSamples | Export-Counter -Path $tempFile -FileFormat CSV -Force ;

# if your output file doesn't exist, copy the entire tmp file, including the CSV header
if (!(Test-Path $outputFile)) {
  Get-Content $tempFile | Out-File -Encoding ASCII $outputFile ;

# otherwise, just grab the last rows which contains the samples and append it to the existing output file
} else {
  Get-Content $tempFile -Last $maxSamples | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -Append $outputFile ;
}
```

Every time you run this, it will append to the output file.  If you are starting over, just delete the output file, or specify a new output file.